# magento issuue in get order id in app/code/core/mage/sales/model/order/pdf/invoice.php

Tags: php, magento

Hi i am trying to get `increment id` on `invoice.php` page http://prntscr.com/g0tyje
that is already coming in below protected http://prntscr.com/g0tyow

how we can use in protected to get increment id  please help me to solve this issue Thanks in advance.

```
 $orderId         = '100000006';     
 $order           = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
 $shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();     
 $vikk            = $shippingAddress['postcode'];     
 if($vikk == 110028){ 
    $lines[0][] = array( 'text' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax(CGST)'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right' );
  } else { 
    $lines[0][] = array( 'text' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax(IGST)'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right' );
  }
```

Comment: Please post your code as text in your question by [edit]ing it and NOT as images. This drastically decreases your chances in someone helping you as it helps to have access to the code. And believe me: Noone will type the code of the image ;)

Comment: I need to change invoice Tax name change based on Zip code so i want to get increment id here dynamically instead of static value http://prntscr.com/g0u1oc

Comment: $orderId = '100000006';
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderId);
$shippingAddress = $order->getShippingAddress();
$vikk= $shippingAddress['postcode'];
    if($vikk == 110028){
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax(CGST)'),
            'feed'  => 495,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        }
        else {
             $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax(IGST)'),
            'feed'  => 495,
            'align' => 'right'
        );
        }

Comment: [edit] that to your question please. As you can see this gets messy in comments. Once pasted in your question you can highlight it and press Ctrl+K or `{}` symbol in the top of the editing area to format as code.

Comment: I dont have idea if anyone can help me to solve this issue i will be very thankful to him.

Comment: Thank you BilalJohn for help me to edit but still i am facing this issue not getting order id  dynamically.

Comment: Can you post the code itself instead of screen shots. so that it will be easier to debug

Comment: unable to post it showing too long http://prntscr.com/g0ui1k

Comment: don't post it on comments.. update it in the question

Comment: one more thing.. you shouldn't edit this core file `app/code/core/mage/sales/model/order/pdf/invoice.php`... You should override it

Comment: read this http://inchoo.net/magento/overriding-magento-blocks-models-helpers-and-controllers/

Comment: you can modify it by putting into local code pool.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are editing the file `app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php`

you should override this file by creating a module, I have created this for you, you just need to copy these files into your magento install. also you will need to add your code in, i have just made the variable $incrementId available to your function

app/etc/modules/Vikash_Pdf.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vikash_Pdf>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Mage_Sales/>

            </depends>
        </Vikash_Pdf>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Vikash/Pdf/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Vikash_Pdf>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Vikash_Pdf>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <sales>
                <rewrite>
                    <order_pdf_invoice>Vikash_Pdf_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice</order_pdf_invoice>
                </rewrite>
            </sales>
        </models>
    </global>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Vikash/Pdf/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

```
<?php
class Vikash_Pdf_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice extends Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Pdf_Invoice
{
    /**
     * Draw header for item table
     *
     * @param Zend_Pdf_Page $page
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _drawHeader(Zend_Pdf_Page $page, $incrementId = null)
    {
        if($incrementId){
            var_dump($incrementId);die;
        }
        /* Add table head */
        $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
        $page->setLineColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
        $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
        $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y -15);
        $this->y -= 10;
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_RGB(0, 0, 0));

        //columns headers
        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Products'),
            'feed' => 35
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('SKU'),
            'feed'  => 290,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Qty'),
            'feed'  => 435,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Price'),
            'feed'  => 360,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Tax'),
            'feed'  => 495,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lines[0][] = array(
            'text'  => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Subtotal'),
            'feed'  => 565,
            'align' => 'right'
        );

        $lineBlock = array(
            'lines'  => $lines,
            'height' => 5
        );

        $this->drawLineBlocks($page, array($lineBlock), array('table_header' => true));
        $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
        $this->y -= 20;
    }

    /**
     * Return PDF document
     *
     * @param  array $invoices
     * @return Zend_Pdf
     */
    public function getPdf($invoices = array())
    {
        $this->_beforeGetPdf();
        $this->_initRenderer('invoice');

        $pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
        $this->_setPdf($pdf);
        $style = new Zend_Pdf_Style();
        $this->_setFontBold($style, 10);

        foreach ($invoices as $invoice) {
            $incrementId = $invoice->getIncrementId();
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($invoice->getStoreId());
                Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($invoice->getStoreId());
            }
            $page  = $this->newPage();
            $order = $invoice->getOrder();
            /* Add image */
            $this->insertLogo($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add address */
            $this->insertAddress($page, $invoice->getStore());
            /* Add head */
            $this->insertOrder(
                $page,
                $order,
                Mage::getStoreConfigFlag(self::XML_PATH_SALES_PDF_INVOICE_PUT_ORDER_ID, $order->getStoreId())
            );
            /* Add document text and number */
            $this->insertDocumentNumber(
                $page,
                Mage::helper('sales')->__('Invoice # ') . $incrementId
            );
            /* Add table */
            $this->_drawHeader($page, $incrementId);
            /* Add body */
            foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
                if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
                    continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }
            /* Add totals */
            $this->insertTotals($page, $invoice);
            if ($invoice->getStoreId()) {
                Mage::app()->getLocale()->revert();
            }
        }
        $this->_afterGetPdf();
        return $pdf;
    }

    /**
     * Create new page and assign to PDF object
     *
     * @param  array $settings
     * @return Zend_Pdf_Page
     */
    public function newPage(array $settings = array(), $incrementId = null)
    {
        /* Add new table head */
        $page = $this->_getPdf()->newPage(Zend_Pdf_Page::SIZE_A4);
        $this->_getPdf()->pages[] = $page;
        $this->y = 800;
        if (!empty($settings['table_header'])) {
            $this->_drawHeader($page, $incrementId);
        }
        return $page;
    }
}
```